# Edição de row por um textBox e recebimento no dataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Eu tenho uma classe que possui dois métodos que recebem o que é digitado nas `textBox`, tudo isso armazenado em um `dataTable` (sem banco de dados). Quando eu clico em uma linha (`Row`) da `dataGridView` eu mostro os valores salvos no `dataTable` de volta na `textBox` e assim consigo alterar o valor da `textBox`, mas não salvar na `dataTable` pois não sei como adicionar essa alteração.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeceria muito.

```
<public class Dados
{
    private string _nome; 
    private string _email;

    public Dados(string nome, string email)
    {
        this._nome = nome;
        this._email = email;
    }

    public string Nome
    {
        get{return _nome;}
        set{_nome = value;}
    }

    public string Endereco
    {
        get{return _email;}

        set{_email = value;}
    }

    public string AlterarNome
    {
        get{return _email;}
        set{_email = value;}
    }

    public string AlterarEndereco
    {
        get{return _email;}

        set{_email = value;}
    }


}>
```

//Parte do Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dt.Columns.Add("Nome", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Email", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

//salvar o que foi digitado
private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Pessoa dados = new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_email.Text);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["Nome"] = dados.Nome;
    dr["Email"] = dados.Email;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}



//botão para editar
private void alterarToolStripMenu_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //espera

    dataGridView1.Update();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();

}

//botão excluir row/cliente
private void excluirToolStripMenu_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indexDaLinhaSelecionada = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(indexDaLinhaSelecionada);

    dataGridView1.Update();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}>
```

Comment: Veja se consigo te ajudar... não sei se o seu problema é setar o valor para o DataRow do DataTable ou se é pegar o valor do RowIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
precisa ter o indice da linha (rowIndex)
e tirar a opção de ReadOnly e setar conforme exemplo abaixo:

(rowIndex vc pega da grid conforme linha selecionada é um inteiro)

```
     foreach(DataColumn col in dataTable1.Columns)
        {
            col.ReadOnly = false;
        }

  //  ... dataTable1.Rows[0] por exemplo
        int rowIndex = 0; 
        dataRow1[rowIndex]["Nome"] = "novoNome";
        dataRow1[rowIndex]["Email"] = "novo@email.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom primeira coisa, ou você trabalha com a classe (`class`) em um lista tipada ou você trabalha com `DataTable`, no seu código por exemplo a classe não serve pra nada, você pode atribuir diretamente os valores pelo `DataTable`

A sua duvida seria no momento de atualizar os dados, já visto que precisa saber o índice da linha que está alterando, que pode ser armazenado em uma variável no inicio da classe do `Form` assim:

```
public int Index { get; set; } = 0;
```

e no duplo clique setar essa variável para o índice do `Row` que foi clicado:

```
if (DataGridViewDados.CurrentRow.Index >= 0)
{
    Index = DataGridViewDados.CurrentRow.Index;
    TxtNome.Text = DataGridViewDados.Rows[Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    TxtEmail.Text = DataGridViewDados.Rows[Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

no momento de clicar no botão para gravar as alterações passe novamente o indice da linha com os valores:

```
DataRow row = DataTableDados.Rows[Index];
row["Nome"] = TxtNome.Text;
row["Email"] = TxtEmail.Text;
```

pronto assim você já está atualizando os dados no `DataTable`.

---

***Código completo:***

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public DataTable DataTableDados { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; } = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Layout_Datatable();
            DataGridViewDados.DataSource = DataTableDados;
        }

        private void Layout_Datatable()
        {
            if (DataTableDados == null)
            {
                DataTableDados = new DataTable("Dados");
                DataTableDados.Columns.Add("Nome", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                DataTableDados.Columns.Add("Email", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                DataTableDados.Columns["Nome"].Unique = false;
                DataTableDados.Columns["Nome"].AllowDBNull = false;
                DataTableDados.Columns["Email"].Unique = false;
                DataTableDados.Columns["Email"].AllowDBNull = false;
            }
        }

        private void SetButtonTextBox(bool status = true)
        {
            TxtEmail.Clear();
            TxtEmail.Enabled = status;
            TxtNome.Clear();
            TxtNome.Enabled = status;
            BtuNovo.Visible = !status;
            BtuAlterar.Visible = !status;
            BtuSalvar.Visible = status;
            BtuCancelar.Visible = status;
            Tag = default(object);
            Index = default(int);
        }

        private void Update_DataGridView()
        {
            DataGridViewDados.Refresh();
            DataGridViewDados.Update();
        }

        private void BtuNovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            SetButtonTextBox();
            TxtNome.Focus();
            Tag = 1;
        }

        private void BtuAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataTableDados.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(
                    "Deseja alterar?",
                    "Alterar",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1))
                {

                    SetButtonTextBox();
                    TxtNome.Focus();
                    Tag = 2;

                    if (DataGridViewDados.CurrentRow.Index >= 0)
                    {
                        Index = DataGridViewDados.CurrentRow.Index;
                        TxtNome.Text = DataGridViewDados.Rows[Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        TxtEmail.Text = DataGridViewDados.Rows[Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nenhum dado consta para alteração", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }           
        }

        private void BtuSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Tag != null)
            {
                if (Tag.Equals(1))
                {
                    DataRow row = DataTableDados.NewRow();
                    row["Nome"] = TxtNome.Text;
                    row["Email"] = TxtEmail.Text;
                    DataTableDados.Rows.Add(row);

                }
                else if (Tag.Equals(2))
                {
                    DataRow row = DataTableDados.Rows[Index];
                    row["Nome"] = TxtNome.Text;
                    row["Email"] = TxtEmail.Text;
                }
                SetButtonTextBox(false);
                Update_DataGridView();
            }
        }

        private void BtuCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetButtonTextBox(false);
            Update_DataGridView();
        }

        private void DataGridViewDados_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                BtuAlterar.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nesse código completo estão as operações de ***Novo***, ***Alterar*** e ***Salvar*** verifique nos botões cada operação realizada.